# ways to fill n places with fixed values in a given range and avoid diplicates formed.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

what are the number of ways in which we can fill n places with 2 fixed values and rest places with values between the 2 selected ones such that we get no duplicates?

example : n=4 , fixed values 1 and 3

```
case 1 : fix 1 on position 1 and 3 on position 2

1 3 1 1
1 3 1 2
1 3 2 1
1 3 2 2
1 3 1 3
1 3 3 1
1 3 3 3
1 3 2 3
1 3 3 2

case 2 : fix 1 on position 1 and 3 on position 3

1 1 3 1
1 1 3 2
1 2 3 1
1 2 3 2
1 3 3 2
1 2 3 3
1 3 3 1
1 1 3 3
1 3 3 3
now in case 1 and 2 : 1 3 3 3 and 1 3 3 1 and 1 3 3 2 are repeating 

case 3 : ....similarly other cases follow
```

what i have done till now is :`nC2 * POWER( (max-min+1) , n-2 ) - duplicates` but not able to subtract duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by repeating? Are the cases supposed to be considered separately, which is suggested by the way you phrased the question.

Comment: by repeating i meant that count should not be 9+9 , but `9 + 9 -3` because we counted `1 3 3 3 and 1 3 3 1 and 1 3 3 2` 2 times. these are "repeating"...
NO , the 2 cases were just for explaining the question, so cases are not to be considered seperately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the **in-and-out principle**, also known as the [**inclusion-exclusion principle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let's say $n\ge2$ and call the fixed values $x$ and $x+q$ where $q\ge1$. (In your example, $n=4,x=1,q=2$.)

There are $(q+1)^n$ ways to fill the $n$ positions with integers in the range $[x,x+q]$. This is an overcount, because some of the ways we counted miss $x$ or $x+q$ or both.

Of the $(q+1)^n$ things we counted, there are $q^n$ that miss $x$; these are the ways of filling the $n$ positions with integers in $[x+1,q]$. Count them out: that leaves $(q+1)^n-q^n$ ways.

By the same token, our original overcount included $q^n$ things that miss $x+q$; count those out too. That leaves $(q+1)^n-2q^n$.

But now we have undercounted, because things that miss **both** $x$ and $x+q$ have been counted out **twice**. There are $(q-1)^n$ of those, so count them back in to get the correct final answer:$$(q+1)^n-2q^n+(q-1)^n.$$

In your example with $n=4,x=1,q=2$ we get $81-2\cdot16+1=50$. Is that what you got?

To check my answer, let's count them by brute force.

There are $19$ ways starting with a $1$, namely: $1113$, $1123$, $1131$, $1132$, $1133$, $1213$, $1223$, $1231$, $1232$, $1233$, $1311$, $1312$, $1313$, $1321$, $1322$, $1323$, $1331$, $1332$, $1333$.

There are $12$ ways starting with a $2$, namely: $2113$, $2123$, $2131$, $2132$, $2133$, $2213$, $2231$, $2311$, $2312$, $2313$, $2321$, $2331$.

There are $19$ ways starting with a $3$. I'm getting tired of typing, so just take the list of $19$ ways starting with a $1$ and change all the $1$s to $3$s and the $3$s to $1$s.

The grand total (no duplicates!) is $19+12+19=50$.

**P.S.** To explain the solution more formally: If $S$ is a set, $|S|$ denotes the number of elements in $S$. Let $S$ be the set of all sequences of length $n$ taking (integer) values in the closed interval $[x,x+q]$; then $|S|=(q+1)^n$. Let $A$ be the subset of $S$ consisting of all sequences in $S$ in which $x$ is missing; in other words, $A$ is the set of all sequences taking values in the interval $[x+1,x+q]$; so $|A|=q^n$. Let $B$ be the set of all sequences in $S$ in which $x+q$ is missing; so $|B|=q^n$. The union $A\cup B$ is the set of all sequences in $S$ missing $x$ or $x+q$ or both. The **inclusion-exclusion** principle says that $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|$. The intersection $A\cap B$ is the set of all sequences in $S$ missing both $x$ and $x+q$, in other words, the set of all sequences taking values in the interval $[x+1,x+q-1]$, and so $|A\cap B|=(q-1)^n$, and $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|=q^n+q^n-(q-1)^n$=2q^n-(q-1)^n. That's the number of elements in $S$ which do **not** contain both an $x$ and an $x+q$. Since there are a total of $(q+1)^n$ of sequences in $S$, the number of sequences which do contain an $x$ and a $q$ is equal to $|S|-|A\cup B|=(q+1)^n-[2q^n-(q-1)^n]=(q+1)^n-2q^n+(q-1)^n$.

Comment: don't you think that sequences would be repeated this way?
like i asked in question `1 3 3 1` would be counted twice.

Comment: What do you get for the total number (after eliminating duplicates) in your example? I counted $50$, how far off am I?

Comment: actually i also get 50 but i am not able to prove how above method is right and is able to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: Do you know the inclusion-exclusion principle? Did you follow the link to the Wikipedia page about that?

Comment: ok understood thanks you explained it really in detail.